# while planning motion my model brokes in moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am created a URDF file and moveit configuration file for my 6-DOF arm in ros-hydro. Now while I running demo.launch and plan to a random position my model collapse ( Its pic added below). I am not found this problem before while i working in groovy. What may be the problem

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97286/while-planning-motion-my-model-brokes-in-moveit/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is bug in ros hydro in 32 bit OS

---

Originally posted by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) with karma: 313 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0